# Why my Pinterest App is still in pending state?

Tags: pinterest

I requested to approve an app in Pinterest almost 1 month back. But still the app status is in "pending" state. And I haven't got any reply from Pinterest asking for more details if they are looking for some.

Appreciate any help or in site on this situation. And any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

-- Siva

Comment: Hi, did you ever had an approval? We are currently in the very same situation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because related to app store and not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

Even in pending state, you can use your app without problem. I think the only difference between approved and pending is you can hit more traffic limit.

Comment: Yes. We can use(as long as you are one of the collaborator in pinterest app). But we are looking for customers to use our app to post in their pinterest accounts. And so requested insight on this if any one faced this issue ever or pinterest takes time to respond?

Comment: But there is no way to access any app credentials